# read doc file very fast c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to extract text from .doc files, I use this code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = FileToSave_path + FileNameToSave + ".doc";
object readOnly = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
string totaltext = "";
for (int p = 0; p < docs.Paragraphs.Count; p++)
{
    ExtractedHTML += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[p + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
}

docs.Close();
word.Quit();
```

the problem is that this code is very slow, I have many .doc files with many paragraphs
any other way to extract from .doc fast ?

Comment: Go the OpenXML way. They are much faster compared to interop. These are the two I can think of https://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/, http://docx.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you @runDOSRun, but I am talking about .doc not .docx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so slow because you need to 'start' Word every time (this happens underwater, but there are still some startup routines which it needs to perform). So it helps if you close only the document and not Word itself (with `word.Quit();`).

You can also look into third party libraries which can open .doc files without the help of Word. For .docx files, you can use Microsoft's own [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).

Comment: If opening Word is the problem, it might also be an option to re-use the same Word instance.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think the problem is in the loop, can I read the whole document once? any .doc library to do so? thanks